# Do I need visa to either transit or leave the airport during a long layover in Zurich?

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, transit-visas, tourist-visas

I'm an Indian national and I will be travelling from US to India with a 23-hour layover in Zurich.

I have a valid US F-1 visa student visa and might be interested in leaving the airport for some sightseeing.

If I do need a visa, what type and documents, and how long would it take to get?

Comment: You don't need a visa if you're willing to stay in the airport.  To leave the airport you'll need a type C short-stay visa, the same as you'd need for any tourist visit.

Comment: @phoog Thanks! But I need clear information about procedure.

Comment: Have you visited the website of the Swiss consulate responsible for your place of residence? If so, and you don't understand the information there, you can edit this question to explain, or post a new question.